# Why does having an "include" of a file that doesn't exist slow my entire PHP page to a crawl (on IIS 7.5)?

Tags: php, performance, iis, include, windows-server-2012

As an example, let's say I have the following in my PHP code at the top of a file:

```
include ($collectiontype."s/collectors_config.php");
```

What I'm noticing is that if that include file doesn't exists, let's say at the path `bogus/collectors_config.php`, then the execution of my PHP page slows a crawl. If it does exist, then the page is super fast.

I am running PHP 5.4 on IIS 7.5 (Windows Server 2012).

Why is that? Is there some recursive lookup that is killing performance looking for a file that isn't there? Is there a setting in php.ini that I need to change?

Looking for some insight here into why this could be happening.

Comment: this behavior not exist in Apache or at least on My system :)

Comment: @Akam That's why I mentioned I am running IIS.

Comment: Yes, do you tested same script on different system?

Comment: Depending on your `include_path`, yes it's doing *some recursive lookup that is killing performance looking for a file that isn't there*.